# How to replace the existing version of an image in carrierwave?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

I want to replace the version of an image with my custom image.

```
MyUploader < IconBase
  DIEMENSION = [200,200]

  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_fill => [152,152]
  end

  def filename
    "foo.png"
  end
end
```

Here I can recreate the thumb version image.But i want to replace thumb version with my custom image. Any idea ??

Answer (score 0):

inside your thumb version, put only your file name as a string, comment out the process method.

it's not tested, but i assume this is the way it works. also try both filename and filename with full path

(sorry if this isn't a proper answer but i can't use comments yet)